# Gravity forms css infering layout

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm migrating the contact form from here: http://www.niclaims.co.uk/ to the new Wordpress version using Gravity Forms (the original ASP site).

However, I am unfamiliar with the way it controls the CSS of the form output. I have turned it off in the options, but the widget seems to add extra padding on the one I am making here: http://niclaims.webdeveloperbelfast.com/ . It's the contact form on the home page side bar I need help with. How can I remove this extra padding?

Also, I need to know, with Gravity Forms is there a way that I can have the labels inline in the text boxes and disappear on focus?

Comment: I believe that the downvotes came from an unclear statement of your problem, not entirely due to the language used. I've tried to rewrite your question to make it clear what you need help with, but if I got this wrong feel free to correct my terminology.

Answer (score 0):

i am not a css prodigy and have never used gravity forms before. But you can try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropifi-contact-widget/ which offers a much easier way to create contact forms without touching any code. Hope it helps!